# Override only the monospaced font?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Is it possible to override only the monospace font used in Angular Material? I need all the `<code>foo</code>` blocks to use a font that has zeros `0` that are different that capital ohs `O`.

Comment: You can style the <code> tag in css: code {font-family: Arial, sans-serif}.

Answer (score 0):

Nathanial Flick got me on the correct path.

I edited `src/index.html` to add the font I wanted:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also edited `src/styles.css` to add:

```css
code { font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace; }
```

Works great! Thanks Nathanial!